# Get maven surefire to run on classpath with module-info.java file present

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to write a library that can be run on the module path without trouble, but I'm using the `org.testcontainers` package for tests, and they have a number of dependencies that doesn't work on the module path.

These are the errors I get when trying to run surefire with my `module-info.java` present:

> [WARNING] Can't extract module name from visible-assertions-2.1.1.jar:
>   TtyCheck.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not
>   allowed in module) [WARNING] Can't extract module name from
>   native-lib-loader-2.0.2.jar: native.lib.loader: Invalid module name:
>   'native' is not a Java identifier [WARNING] Can't extract module name
>   from junixsocket-native-common-2.0.4.jar: junixsocket.native.common:
>   Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier

These lead to further problems with class not found.

Note that this is a run time problem, the code compiles without problem and the produced jar works.

As far as I have understood the surefire documentation, it tries to run tests on the module path if the `module-info.java` file is present.

Is there any way to disable this behavior and fore maven surefire to run the tests on the class path instead of the module path?

Comment: Please show your full pom files ....

Comment: @khmarbaise here is a complete example https://github.com/alexanderkjall/pgsql2/tree/convert-to-maven if the module-info.java file is deleted the tests starts working

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by adding:

```
    <configuration>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    </configuration>
```

To the maven-surefire-plugin plugin section, that gave me the warning `[WARNING] useSystemClassloader setting has no effect when not forking`.

Answer (score 1):

As of Surefire 3.0.0-M2, the correct solution is to set:

```
<configuration>
  <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
</configuration>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useModulePath for more information.